# How to disable or highlight the dates in JCalendar

Tags: java, swing, simpledateformat, jcalendar, jdatechooser

In my case i want to disable or highlight dates in Java calendar. I used `JCalendar` and `DateChooserCombo` and could not find a way to do it. Finally, I tried the below code and it also was not successful.

For example: I want to disable all dates from `14-09-13` to `23-09-13`.

```
DateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-mm-dd");
try {
     Date d1 = formatter.parse("2013-09-14");
     Date d2 = formatter.parse("2013-09-23");
     jCalendar1.setSelectableDateRange(d1, d2);
 } catch (ParseException ex) {
    ex.printStackTrace();
 }
```

Answer (score 8):

I know this has been inactive for a while but hopefully it can be useful to someone. The key here is implement `IDateEvaluator` interface which is intended to validate if a date is special or invalid. Unfortunately there's only one concrete implementation provided with [JCalendar](http://www.toedter.com/en/jcalendar/) library which is `MinMaxDateEvaluator`class, but taking this as start point is not so complicated.

#### RangeEvaluator

Here is an example of implementation, please pay special attention to `isInvalid(Date date)` method. Also you may want to look at `DateUtil` class which is also part of `JCalendar` library.

```
class RangeEvaluator implements IDateEvaluator {

    private DateUtil dateUtil = new DateUtil();

    @Override
    public boolean isSpecial(Date date) {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public Color getSpecialForegroundColor() {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public Color getSpecialBackroundColor() {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public String getSpecialTooltip() {
        return null;
    }
    @Override
    public boolean isInvalid(Date date) {
        return dateUtil.checkDate(date);
        // if the given date is in the range then is invalid
    }        

    /**
     * Sets the initial date in the range to be validated.
     * @param startDate 
     */
    public void setStartDate(Date startDate) {
        dateUtil.setMinSelectableDate(startDate);
    }

    /**
     * @return the initial date in the range to be validated.
     */
    public Date getStartDate() {
        return dateUtil.getMinSelectableDate();
    }

    /**
     * Sets the final date in the range to be validated.
     * @param endDate 
     */
    public void setEndDate(Date endDate) {
        dateUtil.setMaxSelectableDate(endDate);
    }

    /**
     * @return the final date in the range to be validated.
     */
    public Date getEndDate() {
        return dateUtil.getMaxSelectableDate();
    }        
}
```

#### Using `RangeEvaluator`class

There is an example of using `RangeEvaluator` class below. Please note the range from September 14th to September 23rd is disabled.

```
SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");

RangeEvaluator evaluator = new RangeEvaluator();
evaluator.setStartDate(dateFormat.parse("2013-09-14"));
evaluator.setEndDate(dateFormat.parse("2013-09-23"));

JCalendar calendar = new JCalendar(Locale.US);
calendar.getDayChooser().addDateEvaluator(evaluator); // evaluator must be added to a JDayChooser object
```

#### Screenshot

[image]