# Disable multiple date ranges jDateChooser

Tags: java, swing, jcalendar, jdatechooser

I want to disable multiple date ranges on a [JCalendar](http://toedter.com/jcalendar/). I'm following [these steps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18820257/how-to-disable-or-highlight-the-dates-in-java-calendar/20753026#20753026), but I need to know how can I add multiple date evaluators.
Help me please, thanks.

Update: I don't know why I can't disable the dates on my [JCalendar](http://toedter.com/jcalendar/). I will leave my code here so you guys can check it.

This is my RangeEvaluator class, modified from [this class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18820257/how-to-disable-or-highlight-the-dates-in-java-calendar/20753026#20753026).

```
class RangeEvaluator implements IDateEvaluator {

    private DateUtil dateUtil = new DateUtil();

    @Override
    public boolean isSpecial(Date date) {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public Color getSpecialForegroundColor() {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public Color getSpecialBackroundColor() {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public String getSpecialTooltip() {
        return null;
    }
    @Override
    public boolean isInvalid(Date date) {
        return dateUtil.checkDate(date);
        // if the given date is in the range then is invalid
    }        

    /**
     * Sets the initial date in the range to be validated.
     * @param startDate 
     */
    public void setStartDate(Date startDate) {
        dateUtil.setMinSelectableDate(startDate);
    }

    /**
     * @return the initial date in the range to be validated.
     */
    public Date getStartDate() {
        return dateUtil.getMinSelectableDate();
    }

    /**
     * Sets the final date in the range to be validated.
     * @param endDate 
     */
    public void setEndDate(Date endDate) {
        dateUtil.setMaxSelectableDate(endDate);
    }

    /**
     * @return the final date in the range to be validated.
     */
    public Date getEndDate() {
        return dateUtil.getMaxSelectableDate();
    }        
    @Override
    public String getInvalidTooltip() {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public Color getInvalidBackroundColor() {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public Color getInvalidForegroundColor() {
        return null;
    }
}
```

Here is how I am using the RangeEvaluator class:

```
    RangeEvaluator evaluator = new RangeEvaluator();
    SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-mm-yyyy");
    evaluator.setStartDate(dateFormat.parse("11-09-2014"));
    evaluator.setEndDate(dateFormat.parse("15-09-2014"));
    jCalendar1.getDayChooser().addDateEvaluator(evaluator);
```

Am I missing something?. 
Help me please, Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Based on your update there are two things that happen here.

First is a little mistake when you instatiate your [SimpleDateFormat](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html):

```
SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-mm-yyyy");
```

In this pattern "mm" refers to *minutes* not *months*. It should be:

```
SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy");
```

Second problem is IMHO a bug since day chooser seems to not apply filters until a new date is set or it has to be repainted because of month/year change. You can test it changing month to August and then back to September: dates from 9/11 to 9/15 will be disabled. To solve this inconvenient behavior just set current date explicitely like this:

```
JCalendar calendar = new JCalendar();
calendar.getDayChooser().addDateEvaluator(evaluator);
calendar.setDate(Calendar.getInstance().getTime());
```

---

**Side note:** while this library is very very useful it has a couple of bug/design issues so don't hesitate to ask for help.

Answer (score 4):

Just call `addDateEvaluator()` for each `RangeEvaluator` that you create. This adds the `RangeEvaluator` to a `List dateEvaluators` inside `JDayChooser`. Later, `JDayChooser` iterates over the list when it decides how to draw the day buttons.

Edit: Here's the `RangeEvaluator` I used.

```
private static class RangeEvaluator extends MinMaxDateEvaluator {

    @Override
    public boolean isInvalid(Date date) {
        return !super.isInvalid(date);
    }
}
```

And here's how I used it.

```
RangeEvaluator re = new RangeEvaluator();
re.setMinSelectableDate(...);
re.setMaxSelectableDate(...);
JCalendar jc = new JCalendar();
jc.getDayChooser().addDateEvaluator(re);
```

One problem I noticed is that you have to tell the `JDayChooser` to reconfigure its buttons using the new evaluator. You can fire a property change event or just change a bound property.

```
jc.setCalendar(jc.getCalendar());
```

Comment: Sorry, no. Does your `isInvalid()` ever return true?

Comment: Yes, It's returning true for the dates between evaluator.setStartDate() and evaluator.setEndDate(), but It keeps showing them on the graphic calendar.

Comment: Next, I'd try returning distinct colors from `getInvalidForegroundColor` and `getInvalidBackroundColor` to see the effect.

Comment: I tried but nothing happened, then I checked if my jCalendar is valid with jCalendar1.isValid() and It's returning False.

Comment: @dic19: Can you think of a problem extending `MinMaxDateEvaluator` like this?

Comment: I have added a new answer just because it's too long to be a comment. However IMHO your answer is the right one based on original question. @CatalinaIsland