# How to enable JCalendar buttons after using the addDateEvaluator() method in NetBens?

Tags: java, netbeans, jcalendar

My problem is this. I have a JCalendar in which I disable the days I want through this method.

```java
private void jButtonActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         

    List<DayOfWeek> invalidDays = Arrays.asList(DayOfWeek.MONDAY, DayOfWeek.FRIDAY);
    JCalendar.getDayChooser().addDateEvaluator(new DayOfWeekEvaluator(invalidDays));
    JCalendar.setCalendar(JCalendar.getCalendar());
 
}
```

Until then ok. Getting that way

[My project](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PWGBk.png)

Through another method I want to enable the Jcalendar buttons again, I tried to use `removeDateEvaluator()`.

I tried as follows:

```java
private void jButton2ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         

    List<DayOfWeek> invalidDays = Arrays.asList(DayOfWeek.MONDAY, DayOfWeek.FRIDAY);
    JCalendar.getDayChooser().removeDateEvaluator(new DayOfWeekEvaluator(invalidDays));
    JCalendar.setCalendar(JCalendar.getCalendar());
 
    }
```

But without success.

The `DayOfWeekEvaluator` class I got from the forum is below:

```java
public class DayOfWeekEvaluator implements IDateEvaluator {

    private final List<DayOfWeek> validDaysOfWeek;

    public DayOfWeekEvaluator(List<DayOfWeek> validDaysOfWeek) {
        this.validDaysOfWeek = validDaysOfWeek;
    }

    private DayOfWeek determineDayOfWeek(Date date) {
        Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
        c.setTime(date);
        int dayOfWeek = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK);
        return DayOfWeek.of(convertSundayFirstToMondayFirst(dayOfWeek));
    }

    private int convertSundayFirstToMondayFirst(int sundayFirstValue) {
        // Converts from weeks that are Sunday-Saturday (1-7)
        // to weeks that are Monday-Sunday (1-7)
        if (sundayFirstValue == 1) {
            return 7;
        }
        return sundayFirstValue - 1;
    }

}
```

Comment: [Disable multiple date ranges jDateChooser](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25501373/261156) shows another way to update [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25695372/261156).

Comment: it's work tank you

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Disable multiple date ranges jDateChooser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25501373/disable-multiple-date-ranges-jdatechooser)