# Disable dates JDates Chooser

Tags: java, swing, jcalendar

I'm newbie and I want to disable dates like shown in [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18820257/how-to-disable-or-highlight-the-dates-in-java-calendar?answertab=active#tab-top) but in a `JDateChooser` button. Here is my code and hope you guys can help me.

```
SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");

RangeEvaluator evaluator = new RangeEvaluator();
evaluator.setStartDate(dateFormat.parse("2013-09-14"));
evaluator.setEndDate(dateFormat.parse("2013-09-23"));


JDateChooser calendar = new JDateChooser();
calendar.getCalendar.(evaluator);
// evaluator must be added to a JDayChooser object 

calendar.setSize(180, 25); 
calendar.setLocation(140, 640);
calendar.setVisible(true);
calendar.updateUI();
this.add(calendar);
```

Comment: You need to change the date/calendar, as shown in this possible [duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/q/25501373/230513).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's start with your question: *How to add an `IDateEvaluator` to a `JDateChooser`?* This is a really easy-to-solve problem but you must know the API first:

- `JDayChooser` is a panel with buttons for each day of a month
  displayed in a tabular form.
- `JCalendar` component has a `JDayChooser` embedded and adds the
  ability to change the year and month, updating the day chooser.
- `JDateChooser` displays a `JCalendar` in a popup when you press the selector button.

So you basically need to get the reference to the `JDayChooser` component and add the date evaluator like this:

```
RangeEvaluator evaluator = new RangeEvaluator();
...
JDateChooser dataChooser = new JDateChooser();
dateChooser.getJCalendar().getDayChooser().addDateEvaluator(evaluator);
```

#### Other comments

- Be aware of the buggy behavior described in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25695372/1795530). You
  should set the current date explicitely after adding date
  evaluators to solve this issue.
- You should never call any `updateUI()` method explicitely. It is
  intended to reset the UI property of a component to a value from the
  current Look and Feel.
- Be aware that methods such as `setSize(...)`, `setLocation(...)` or
  `setBounds(...)` are discouraged because Swing is not designed to be used
  with exact components size/location but with [Layout Managers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/howLayoutWorks.html) instead.
  See also [this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7229226/should-i-avoid-the-use-of-setpreferredmaximumminimumsize-methods-in-java-swi).

Comment: You are welcome @Pablo If this worked for you then don't forget to [accept the answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer)