# Java add icon to JCalendar

Tags: java, swing, imageicon, jcalendar

I'm trying to add an icon to a specific day into a `JCalendar`, but I can't.

How can I do that?

I have this code:

```
final JCalendar calendar = new JCalendar();
    JDayChooser day= calendar.getDayChooser();
    day.setAlwaysFireDayProperty(true);
    day.addPropertyChangeListener(new PropertyChangeListener() {
        public void propertyChange(PropertyChangeEvent e) {
            //put icon here
            ImageIcon icon = new ImageIcon("icon.png");
            JLabel label = new JLabel(icon);
            day.add(label);

        }
```

**Edit**: I want the icon in a day.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding an icon to the buttons of a `JDayChooser` is not supported. You'd have to extend `JDayChooser` and modify one of the buttons in the protected array named `days`. As the panel is already fairly crowded, I'm not sure the effect would be appealing.

Alternatively, implement the `IDateEvaluator` interface and alter the colors for your chosen date, as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25501373/230513), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18820257/230513) and other implementing classes in the distribution; the class `com.toedter.calendar.demo.BirthdayEvaluator` illustrates the approach.

```
public boolean isSpecial(Date date) {
    calendar.setTime(date);
    return calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH) == yourSpecialMonth
    && calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH) == yourSpecialDay;
}

public Color getSpecialForegroundColor() {
    return yourSpecialForegroundColor;
}

public Color getSpecialBackroundColor() {
    return yourSpecialBackroundColor;
}
```